# $f: M \rightarrow N$ if $M, N$ are orientable manifolds and $c$ is a regular value then $f^{-1} (c)$ is a orientable manifold.

Tags: analysis, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I need to prove the following result: Let $f: M \rightarrow  N$ be a smooth function, if $M, N$ are orientable manifolds and $c$ is a regular value of $f$ then $f^{-1} (c)$ is a orientable manifold.

Using the implicit function theorem I was able to show that $f^{-1} (c)$ is a manifold.

Indeed, let $p$ be a point in $f^{-1} (c) $. Consider the  coordinates $\phi: U_1 \rightarrow M \cap V_1 $ and $\psi: U_2 \rightarrow N \cap V_2$, such that $p$ $\in$ $V_1$ and  $c$ $\in$ $V_2$.

Since by hipoteses $\psi^{-1} (c)$ is a regular value of  $\psi^{-1} \circ f  \circ \phi$ we can reorder coordinates and find, by implicit function theorem, a function $\varepsilon: V_{0} \rightarrow U_0$ such that  $\psi^{-1} \circ f  \circ \phi ( x , \varepsilon (x)) = \psi^{-1}(c)$.

So we can define the local coordinate $(\Phi , V_0)$ as $\Phi(x) = \phi(x,\varepsilon(x))$. Showing that $f^{-1}(c)$ is a manifold. My problem is prove that this manifold is orientable.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you know about normal bundles (and tangent bundles)?

Comment: Yes! And I know that they are orientable

Comment: So the tangent bundle of your submanifold is the quotient of two orientable bundles, hence orientable.

Comment: How I prove this?

Comment: Define $w_1,\dots,w_k$ to be a (positively) oriented basis for $(E/F)_p$ iff for an oriented basis $v_1,\dots,v_m$ for $F_p$ and $w'_j$ projecting to $w_j$, we have $v_i,w'_j$ an oriented basis for $E_p$. Check local coherence in the obvious way.

Comment: Have you a reference where I can see this with more details?

Comment: One standard reference for such things would be Hirsch's *Differential Topology*, but I'm sure there are lots of others.